# What is the best way to set up zsh with oh-my-zsh, powerlevel10k and nvm?

Tags: zsh, nvm

I'm using zsh on Linux with OhMyZsh and the powerlevel10k theme. I'm also using nvm since I have to switch node versions for different projects.

I'd like to achieve that zsh automatically uses the node version set in the `.nvmrc` file (if one exists). That should be triggered when changing into a directory that has a `.nvmrc` file, but also when opening a terminal (e.g. opening a vscode project, the internal terminal should be set to the respective node version).

I tried the ohmyzsh nvm plugin (with `export NVM_LAZY=true` and `export NVM_AUTOLOAD=true`), but that causes this behavior with powerlevel10k when opening a terminal:

```
[WARNING]: Console output during zsh initialization detected.

When using Powerlevel10k with instant prompt, console output during zsh
initialization may indicate issues.
...
```

The [zsh-nvm](https://github.com/lukechilds/zsh-nvm) plugin works better (with `export NVM_LAZY_LOAD=true` and `export NVM_AUTO_USE=true`). It automatically changes the version when changing directories, however not when opening the terminal.
I achieved that by adding this line to my `.zshrc` file:

```sh
[ -s "./.nvmrc" ] && nvm use > /dev/null 2>&1
```

That does not cause the above mentioned powerlevel10k issue, however the terminal changes the look (applying the powerlevel10k theme) after a couple seconds. I guess that is  because of loading nvm right away (and not lazy loading it anymore). If I open the terminal in a directory without `.npmrc`, it opens fast and with the p10k theme right away.

I can live with this setup, but it is still not ideal and feels hacky. Is there a better way to do it?

*Just for reference, there is also this [issue](https://github.com/lukechilds/zsh-nvm/issues/74) on the zsh-nvm github*